# NodeJS/Angular Edit Request Gets 400 Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

I'm working on an application with Ionic/Angular with a NodeJS backend.I have made an update form where a user can edit/delete a row with. The delete works, but I am having trouble with the edit function. On my console, this gets displayed: http://localhost:3000/api/todos/%7B%22todo%22:%22NewT%22,%22todo_text%22:%22Text%20EditionT%22%7D. I am wondering how would I make the edit request to work.

Below is my code for the server side request:

```
router.put('/api/todos/:_id', function(req, res) {

db.todos.update({
  _id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.body._id)
}, {
  todo: req.body.todo, 
  todo_text: req.body.todo_text
}, {}, function(err, data) {
  res.json(data);
});

});
```

Code for my update form (both delete and edit function). Note that HomeFac is for my services.js, where it directs to the REST API (http://localhost:3000/api/todos/(id number):

```
.controller('UpdateCtrl', function($stateParams, $rootScope, $scope, HomeFac) {  
id = $stateParams.id;  

$scope.todo = {}; 

HomeFac.getBeer(id).success(function(data) {  

      var met = data[0]; 

      $scope.todo.todo = met.todo; 
      $scope.todo.todo_text = met.todo_text; 
});

$scope.edit = function(id, inputs) {  

    var inputs = { 
        todo : $scope.todo.todo, 
        todo_text : $scope.todo.todo_text
     };  

    data = angular.toJson(inputs); 

    HomeFac.updateBeer($stateParams.id, data
    ).then(function(id, data) { 
      alert("edited!"); 
    }); 
}; 

$scope.delete = function() { 
   HomeFac.deleteBeer(id);
}; 

});
```

Beer Service in services.js

```
_BeerService.updateBeer = function(todo, _id) { 
 return $http.put(urlBase + '/' + _id, todo); 
};
```

Comment: Can you show the updateBeer function?

Comment: @LeandroZubrezki Just added the code.

Comment: Are you getting the request in the server? Add a log there and check what's happening. Also add a error function for the promise so you know if it fails

Comment: The only front end thing that matters is what the incoming request is, so I'd simplify the question to "this request gets this response given this server side code".

Comment: Some questions: is it hitting the route? Is `req.body` what you expect it to be? Is the callback being ran? If so, what is `error` and `data`?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because `req.body._id` is `undefined`. You're probably looking for `req.params._id`. Given that it's undefined, the [update](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#update) function isn't able to find the correct document.

Note: You don't have to make your url parameter `_id`. URL parameters are like function parameters: you could name them whatever you want, and so you probably want to name it something that is more convenient, like `id`.